# Format Error in a calculation in C++

Tags: c++, math

I need help because I have a program in C++. It calculates a number with some decimals correct.I need to show it with this format `_._ _ D _ _`

But I only know to express in this format `_._ _ e _ _`

this is an example:

```
fprintf(arxiu,"%1.2f \t %u \t %1.16f \t %1.16f \t %1.2e\n",x,k,resultat,Bessel,error);
5.55e-17
```

And this is that I want:

```
2.22D-16
```

Is this implemented in C++ or do I need a function that compares the error and shows it like a ten exponential?

Thanks.

Comment: Some phrases didn't make much sense, I tried to correct them, hope I didn't change the meaning.

Comment: What is this `_._ _ D _ _` format?

Comment: Thanks and yes it is that i want.

Comment: It is the follow 0.11 * 10^-12

Comment: JordiM, it appears you don't understand what 5.55e-17 means. It means 5.55 * 10^(-17). The only difference between Fortran's D format and C/C++'s e format is the use of the letter 'D' versus the letter 'e'. The 'e' means 'power of 10 exponent'. It has nothing to do with the number *e* (2.718281828…).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and all you need is formatting, how about this:

```
char bf[30];
sprintf(bf, "%1.2f", value);
char *p = strchr(bf, 'e');
if (p) *p = 'D';
fprintf(arxiu, "%s", bf);
```

It's C rather than C++, but since you are using fprintf yourself, I thought you may find it useful. You may want to put this code in a little functor for reusability.

Comment: But in this case you get for exemple 0.11*e^12 no?? i need the error in  power of 10.
I am wrong?

Comment: In C and C++ 10e+02 means 10*10. It's not the 'e' from math. So it is really a power of 10. I simply replaced 'e' with 'D'.